# Hide and Show to perform with same button using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the below HTML file, and I want to expand the hidden table when I click the button tab which is implemented successfully and need to implement when I tried to click the button the second time should hide the specific table which is opened by button earlier.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.data_table').hide();
  $('.button').on('click', function() {
    $('.data_table').hide();
    $(this).parent().next().find('table.data_table').show();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="tab">
  <div>
    <button type="button" class="button">DATA_1</button>
  </div>
  <div class="logtitude">
    <table class="data_table">
      <tr>
        <th>XXX</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>YYY</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div>
    <button type="button" class="button">DATA_2</button>
  </div>
  <div class="logtitude">
    <table class="data_table">
      <tr>
        <th>AAA</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>YYY</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div>
    <button type="button" class="button">DATA_3</button>
  </div>
  <div class="logtitude">
    <table class="data_table">
      <tr>
        <th>BBB</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>YYY</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

I need to click the same button to hide the table which is opened earlier.

Comment: Try using toggle()

Comment: I used toggle() instead of show() but no luck.

Comment: Remove this line $('.data_table').hide(); and change the following to
    $(this).parent().next().find('table.data_table').toggle();

Comment: great....I let me try that.

Comment: It works like charm...I upvoted your answer. thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `toggle` method for this. Basically `$('.data_table').hide()` inside your click event was causing issues.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.data_table').hide();
  $('.button').on('click', function() {
    $(this).parent().next().find('table.data_table').toggle();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
      <body>
        <div id="tab">
          <div>
            <button type="button" class="button">DATA_1</button>
          </div>
          <div class="logtitude">
             <table class="data_table">
             <tr>
             <th>XXX</th>
             </tr>
             <tr>
             <td>YYY</td>
             </tr>
             </table>
           </div>
          <div>
            <button type="button" class="button">DATA_2</button>
          </div>
          <div class="logtitude">
             <table class="data_table">
             <tr>
             <th>AAA</th>
             </tr>
             <tr>
             <td>YYY</td>
             </tr>
             </table>
          </div>
          <div>
            <button type="button" class="button">DATA_3</button>
          </div>
          <div class="logtitude">
             <table class="data_table">
             <tr>
             <th>BBB</th>
             </tr>
             <tr>
             <td>YYY</td>
             </tr>
             </table>
          </div>
        </div>
       </body>
     </html>
```

Comment: @ArrchanaMohan No problem happy to help :) You should really choose an answer that helped you so others can know that this question is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

use `.toggle()` instead of `.hide()` , if i understand correctly you want to open and close the table with the same button see below

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.button').on('click', function() {
    $('.data_table').toggle();
  });

})
```

```css
div.data_table {
  border: 2px dashed #000;
  height: 200px;
  width: 95%;
  margin-top: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="button">CLICK me to toggle the below div</button>
<div class="data_table">show hide this elemnt</div>
```

Comment: I tried the toggle() instead of hide(), but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by easily with Jquery toggle function. As this is an example you to you.

```js
$(function(){
$(".data_table").hide();
$('.button').on('click', function() {
     $(this).parent().next().find('table.data_table').toggle();
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
      <body>
        <div id="tab">
          <div>
            <button type="button" class="button">DATA_1</button>
          </div>
          <div class="logtitude">
             <table class="data_table">
             <tr>
             <th>XXX</th>
             </tr>
             <tr>
             <td>YYY</td>
             </tr>
             </table>
           </div>
          <div>
            <button type="button" class="button">DATA_2</button>
          </div>
          <div class="logtitude">
             <table class="data_table">
             <tr>
             <th>AAA</th>
             </tr>
             <tr>
             <td>YYY</td>
             </tr>
             </table>
          </div>
          <div>
            <button type="button" class="button">DATA_3</button>
          </div>
          <div class="logtitude">
             <table class="data_table">
             <tr>
             <th>BBB</th>
             </tr>
             <tr>
             <td>YYY</td>
             </tr>
             </table>
          </div>
        </div>
       </body>
     </html>
```

Comment: This is the exact same answer as Zvezdas1989 answered 3 minutes before yours.

Comment: @MasterYoda But I didn't copy that I just made my own. I don't know why such kind of people is ready to give someone negative mark rather than appreciate him/her.

Comment: Most people won't even leave a comment when they downvote. I agree its not constructive but thats how SO works now. If an answer does not add value to a question then you are encouraged to remove it. It happens to me too so please dont feel offended.

Comment: @MasterYoda might be you are right but as you can see my code is little bit  different it means i didn't copied that so you should also check while giving download.